# Divergence of improper integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, divergent-series

I need to prove that this integral diverges:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{x}}{(x^2-3x-4)x}dx$$

And I don't know why. Any help? Thanks!

I know that there are 3 real singularities:

$x=0$,

$x=-1$,

$x=4$

Comment: There are non-integrable singularities at the points in which the denominator is zero.

Comment: Its [Cauchy principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is $\dfrac\pi5\bigg(\sin1-\dfrac{\sin4}4\bigg)$.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Just because **for $x$ near $0$**, we have
$$
\frac{\cos{x}}{(x^2-3x-4)x} \sim -\frac{1}{4x} \tag1
$$ then, for $\epsilon, \,b $ near $0^+$, we have
$$
\int_{\large \epsilon}^b \frac{\cos{x}}{(x^2-3x-4)x} dx \sim -\frac{1}{4}\int_{\large \epsilon}^b\frac{1}{x}dx=-\frac{1}{4}(\log(b)-\log(\epsilon)) \tag2
$$
and, as $\epsilon \to 0^+$, the right hand side of $(2)$ is **divergent** with your initial integral.

Comment: But how can I prove that? Maybe comparing that function with another one? Can you give me an answer with more details? Thanks!

Comment: @Juan I've edited my answer to provide some details. Are you OK with it? Thanks.